# LaTeX table design

Tags: latex

[image]

I want to draw the following table in LaTeX, but can't do this. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Next time, please add a [mre] to your question

Comment: This might be better to ask on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

One possibility with the `diagbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\diagbox{A}{B}& C\\ \hline
a & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much